# Sequencing multiple non-main-thread HttpRequest

Tags: multithreading, async-await, httprequest

In a .net-Application I work with several requests against a Web-Api, using HttpRequest. Since these request are not run on the main thread (async, await...), it is possible that some requests are launched at almost the same time, so a later one is started without a former one being finished. This, in the end, leads to an inconvienient behavior - for example when a first request runs into refreshing access tokens, a second one shall not start a similar request as well, but should wait for the first one to finish and run afterwards.

My idea is to somehow schedule the request in a FiFo-Way, using Arrays/List which are updated everytime one request is finished. A starting request then would check in this list if it is the one in line, or would wait for a start signal by some Array/List watcher.

However, I have strong doubts that this approach is the best/correct way for doing this. Any Help/Hint/Heads Up would be great!

Comment: When and how are you refreshing access tokens?

Comment: My app saves the expiration time of JWTs. So, when I launch any request, this is checked, and when expired I start a Refresh-Request. While this is running, I want to prevent a second request being started (since this would also launch a refresh request what would mess things up).
BUT the token workflow is just mentioned as an example, I want to prevent any "second" request from beeing executed before one started earlier is fully completed.

Comment: You should do that using a [DelegatingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler) and use it with the [HttpClientFactory.Create Method (DelegatingHandler[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclientfactory.create) to create your `HttpClient` instances. That way, you can block all requests until the token is refreshed, if needed.

Comment: Thank you! After a quick look it seems helpful, so I'll get deeper into that.